# Removing or transferring iOS app license

Tags: itunes, ios, applications, itunes-store, license

Simple question:

- I have a TomTom application that was on 5 devices (maximum allowed)
- One of the devices (let's call it D-Vice) breaks/gets lost
- How do I transfer the license from D-Vice to a new device?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The device limit applies only for those devices where "Automatic Downloads" or iTunes Match are turned on.

Snippet from iLounge on "[More than five family devices sharing a single iTunes account](http://www.ilounge.com/index.php/articles/comments/more-than-five-family-devices-sharing-a-single-itunes-account/)":

> Actually, the limit of five devices per iTunes Store account only applies to authorizations for computers using iTunes. Apple actually allows you to have up to ten devices authorized in total for features such as iTunes Match and re-downloading previous purchases from iTunes in the Cloud, up to five of which can be computers running iTunes. So in other words, you could have anywhere from 10 iOS devices and no computers up to five computers and five iOS devices or any combination in between. You can view the number of devices that have been authorized for these features by going into your iTunes Store account information from within iTunes and choosing the Manage Devices option.

---

If you wish to remove the broken or lost device from your account (to avoid issues in the future with respect to other content or automatic downloads), follow Apple's instructions for [Removing an associated device or computer from an Apple ID](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4627):

> To remove a device or computer from your Apple ID:
>
> 1. Open iTunes.
> 2. Sign in to your Apple ID by choosing **Store > Sign In** from the **iTunes** menu.
> 3. Choose **Store > View My Account** from the iTunes menu.
> 4. From the Account Information screen, click **Manage Devices.**
> 5. Click the **Remove** button next to the device name you would like to unassociate.
>
> **Note:** Removing a device from your Apple ID does not override the 90 day timer. The timer must complete 90 days from the day the device was associated before it can be associated to another Apple ID.

Answer (score 3):

You may be confusing the limit of 5 devices that can automatically download new purchases with the ability to sign in and download a past purchase.

You can simply sign in to the App Store on the new device, navigate to purchases and re-download TomTom.

The current terms of service do not limit personal use of apps on multiple devices. You should read the license if you are using the software commercially where the terms specify one license per device or one license per person, but the enforcement is social and not technical. The store doesn't ask when you sign in whether you are licensing something personally or professionally.